# either memory is defective or SD card is, how can i test?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, sd-card, systemd, crash

pi: pi 2
os: respberrian jessie
sd: sandisk 64gb

when i tried to install xvfb on my pi i started getting strange errors from the os, tried `apt-get install -f` and apt-get upgrade``` and ``apt-get clean autoclean` so clean worked install -f didn't do anything and autoclean and upgrade both get me back to the same strange situation.

i suspected sd card issue. it's a 64bg sdcard from sandisk (class 10).
but unlike a PC i can't unmount the root file system and can't reload it as readonly as it's always "busy"
so i tried to fsck on the next boot but could not find a method that works (boot was booting too fast).

below u can see the output of the command when trying to install lsof to see which files or seevices i need to stop in order to remount `ro` so i can use fsck.

`Fetched 365 kB in 1s (318 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libperl4-corelibs-perl.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'javascript-common': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
E: Failed to write temporary StateFile /var/lib/apt/extended_states.tmp
pi@gal-pi:~ $ ls
-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
pi@gal-pi:~ $ df
-bash: /bin/df: No such file or directory
pi@gal-pi:~ $ mount
-bash: mount: command not found
pi@gal-pi:~ $ bash
-bash: /bin/bash: No such file or directory
pi@gal-pi:~ $ cd
-bash: sed: command not found
pi@gal-pi:~ $ cd /
-bash: sed: command not found
-bash: printf: write error: Broken pipe
pi@gal-pi:~ $`

1. anyone experienced it with his pi ?
2. anyone has a good advise how to make forced test with raspberian jessie ? i'm pretty sure it works on systemd but debian made sure systemd will still call old initd scripts at least for some of them... so anyway to force fsck ?
3. last possibility : should i cehck the sd using fsck on a linux system ( i have mint 17.4)

10x!

Comment: It looks like your SD card filesystem is corrupt.  Are you sure you have an adequate Pi power supply?  You can fsck the filesystem with another Linux by putting the card in an accessible SD card reader.

Comment: #3 Shouldn't really be the "last possibility" unless you are afraid of linux -- I think that is what Mint is about? ;) ;) (if so the Pi may give you nightmares). Anyway, WRT to forcing fsck, try adding `fsck.mode=force` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`, but remember that file should be **all one line,** spaces between fields.

Comment: mint is my laptop and i was trying to avoid the external test since  i need now to buy the damn adapter... :-/ 
will do the external test.

Comment: Ok. Used babblocks on the root partition device. Many were found. Could b it. Never buy sdcard on ebay...

Comment: small update, seems like it's not the SDcard after all, tested it on my linux mint 17.4 with card adapter and fsck.ext found no errors, badblocks found 0 bad blocks, i started fearing it may be the RSPI, but  seems like the new ubuntu server for iot i've installed on another sd card works flawlessly... maybe the kenrel got defective in one of my installations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check the filesystem of your SD card by [booting the Pi from USB](http://jonathanmh.com/boot-raspberry-pi-from-a-usb-stick/).

Once booted from USB, you can insert the microSD card and run fsck on it.

Comment: i wrote i use pi 2, this post is for 3 and specifically states that u wont be able to boot from usb this was from pi 2. one way i might be able to boot from usb is to hack cmdline.txt, not sure it will actually work though.

Comment: I updated link to point to a blog post about booting Pi 2 from USB.

Comment: 10x. tried to test your theorm, but then i discovered my usb flash contains mint x86_64.... need to burn rasberian instead.
I have also discovered that id i connect the screen and keyboard and not using ssh i'm passed strait to emergency shell, so i could remount the system ro and run fsck on it.

Comment: put the SD card in any other PC, and check the FS  and disk integrity with the disks utility. (I'll assume all your machines are linux). fsck wont do jack to tell you about physical disk integrity, it only checks the file-system.

Comment: j0h can u recommend one ? AFAIK badblocks does physical test to see for bad blocks and it found many, i mean many it really does seem like the sd is a gonner, probably since i saved many torrents using transmission daemon to sd before moving to external hard drive, could be what killed it.

Comment: since the answer is ok, i'll accept it, the sd was dead, badblocks program did the trick discovering half the sd is defective.....